# Path error In Including file from AmazonProductsAPI Folder

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am trying to create a class file which contains all methods to call Amazon Product API, Report API,Feeds API.
So i have to include all the required files. I got All Amazon API Class folders on same path with this class file and i am including following way:

========================================================

//For getASIN

```
require_once 'AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php';
require_once 'AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Model/GetCompetitivePricingForSKURequest.php';
require_once 'AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Model/SellerSKUListType.php';

//For putPrice (Price Change)
require_once 'FeedsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Client.php';
require_once 'FeedsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Mock.php';
require_once 'FeedsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model/SubmitFeedRequest.php';

//For Updating Quantity and Price From Amazon Report API to Our DB
require_once 'ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Client.php';
require_once 'ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model/RequestReportRequest.php';
require_once 'ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model/GetReportListRequest.php';
require_once 'ReportsAPIClass/src/MarketplaceWebService/Model/GetReportRequest.php';

======================================================

But i am getting error like:

======================================================

    enter code here
    PHP Warning: require_once(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Interface.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/hgfs/keyur On My Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php on line 22

    Warning: require_once(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Interface.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/hgfs/keyur On My Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php on line 22
    PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Interface.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/mnt/hgfs/keyur\ On\ My\ Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src') in /mnt/hgfs/keyur On My Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php on line 22

    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Interface.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/mnt/hgfs/keyur\ On\ My\ Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src') in /mnt/hgfs/keyur On My Mac/webs/keyur.iec.com/htdocs/vendors/AmazonAPI/AmazonProductsAPI/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Client.php on line 22
```

====================================================

As per my computer this paths are correct but don't know what is wrong.
Please Help.........................

Answer (score 1):

The .config.inc.php could help you:

```
/*** 
* OPTIONAL ON SOME INSTALLATIONS
*
* Set include path to root of library, relative to Samples directory.
* Only needed when running library from local directory.
* If library is installed in PHP include path, this is not needed
*/    
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../.');
```